# Call Centre Models

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, poisson-distribution

Can anyone suggest me, which Mathematical(Statistical) methods can be used to predict `incoming`calls by a given time interval at a call centre? Please cite any research paper or a website that may help in this kind of forecasting.

Can incoming calls be treated as a[poisson](/questions/tagged/poisson) distribution in such a scenario?

Comment: It would help if you would be clearer about what needs to be predicted.  Otherwise some fool will answer, "I don't need methods.  I hereby predict calls at a call center" and he/she will be right.

Comment: @rolando2, the above edited question is exactly what I am looking for and I have added an additional question, can you throw some light on that.

Comment: The revisions look helpful and hopefully someone will have more to say to answer you.

Answer (score 2):

A few random hits from a [relevant Google Scholar search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%28%22call%20centre%22%20OR%20%22call%20center%29%20AND%20%28forecasting%20calls%20OR%20predicting%20calls%29&btnG=&hl=en&num=20&as_sdt=0%2C38) gives:

[Call center demand forecasting: improving sales calls prediction accuracy through the combination of statistical methods and judgmental forecast](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/59159/659558470.pdf?sequence=1)

Antipov, A and Meade, N., et al. (2002) [Forecasting call frequency at a financial services call centre](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/pal/01605682/2002/00000053/00000009/2601415). *Journal of the Operational Research Society* 53(9):953--960.

Answer (score 1):

Avramidis, Deslauriers, and L'Ecuyer (2004). [Modeling Daily Arrivals to a Telephone Call Center](http://www.jstor.org/stable/30047947), *Management Science*, 50, 7, pp. 896-908.